# Document is not defined JavaScript in VS code

Tags: javascript

pls help me what's wrong

[image]

js code :

```
let veri;
veri = document.getElementById("header"); 
veri.style.color="blue";
console.log(veri);
```

my ındex.html code :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGzpg.png)

```
<header><h1 class="header">HEADER</h1></header>
```

Comment: here is my index.html

Comment: Node does not have a document or window. You have to view the code in a browser by loading the html file. Your HTML uses `functions.js` but your images talk about `scope.js`, variables `gorab` and `veri`, get the question consistent

Answer (score -2):

in your code you have written: `document.getElementById("header")` this is OK but sometimes you have to use the parent element called "window"

Your code should be like below:

```js
window.document.getElementById("header")
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: This is incorrect. There are no elements with id="header". For this to work you would need something like <header><h1 id="header" class="header">HEADER</h1></header>

Comment: I did but it still doesn't work. ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: What context are you running this JavaScript? Are you running it in a browser (IE, Chrome, etc.)? The document object is part of the DOM in browser and therefore won't exist if you are running elsewhere (node, etc.).

Comment: So so so thank you. It has worked. I am trying to solve that problem two day. Now it works in chrome. Terminal shows Document is not defined but probably it's  related server side. I hope there is no problem anymore. Is it normal VS terminal shows X is not defined but chrome is okey no problem